# Serial downvoter

Tags: discussion

About an hour ago every single one of my questions, and several of my answers, was downvoted within a few minutes. I'm assuming its one person, Would moderators be able to provide some insight into this?

Comment: SE has an algorithm in place that looks for suspicious voting patterns, and this seems like it'd be one of those. The votes should be invalidated soon(ish). Sooner than 6-8 weeks anyway.

Comment: [Happened to me recently](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3277/3961). It was reversed and it was far less abrasive than this one you've experienced. It will probably be reversed before you even read this. @El lol.

Comment: I'm curious to hear how this ends... were the votes undone?

Comment: An entry showed up in my reputation log today "Serial voting was reversed". The original downvotes are still there, but now cancelled out. Thanks to the SE team for putting this system in place.

Comment: Minor correction: the only thing "still there" should be the -2 entries in your rep log that are now cancelled out, the votes themselves should no longer show up on the respective questions.

Comment: Sorry Caleb, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: It happened to me to, today.  The script that catches rep-crimes runs ever 24 hours.... Found that on meta.so

Comment: Did you ever figure out who was the serial downvoter?

Comment: I think only the SE team get to know that, and I don't particularly want to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never fear, such behavioral voting patterns are almost always caught and reversed by an automated set of checks that run through the previous day's vote log. If they don't get restored in 24 hours or so, then we can have the SE team review (normal mods cannot see individual votes or reverse them).